# Masking to accept positive decimals

Tags: vb.net, winforms, textbox

I have a `textBox` and I want it to accept only positive decimals between `0.00` and `20.00`, How can I do that?

Comment: please post some code so that we can help you

Answer (score 0):

If you need to make sure as the user is typing that only decimals are entered then apply an on key up event to it using javascript which checks the contents of the textbox, deleting any offending characters if any are present.

If you just need to check on submit, then do it within the code called on submit of the form.

Comment: Sorry but I'm using winform

Answer (score 0):

You can use a validator on your `TextBox` like this

```
<asp:RangeValidator ID="range" runat="server" 
    ControlToValidate="text1" 
    MinimumValue="0" MaximumValue="20.99" Type="double" />
```

please check this article about [compareValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.comparevalidator.aspx),  [rangeValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.rangevalidator.aspx), [regularExpressionValidator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.regularexpressionvalidator.aspx) for more details

Good luck

Comment: Sorry but I'm using winform

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question.

```
   Private Sub TextBox1_KeyPress(sender As System.Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.KeyPressEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.KeyPress
        If Not Char.IsControl(e.KeyChar) AndAlso Not Char.IsDigit(e.KeyChar) AndAlso e.KeyChar <> "."c Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If

        'for ne decimal point
        If (e.KeyChar = "."c AndAlso (TextBox1).Text.IndexOf("."c) > -1) Then
            e.Handled = True
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_Validating(sender As System.Object, e As System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.Validating
        If Decimal.Parse(TextBox1.Text) >= 0 AndAlso Decimal.Parse(TextBox1.Text) <= 20 Then
            'if positive decimals between 0.00 and 20.00
            'Do stuff
        Else
            'if not positive decimals between 0.00 and 20.00
            e.Cancel = True
        End If
    End Sub
```

Comment: I tried this code but when I write some value like 10.00 it gives me an error in this line `If Decimal.Parse(TextBox1.Text) >= 0 AndAlso Decimal.Parse(TextBox1.Text) <= 2 Then` also when I write some value without . like 11 it won't let me to focus other controls

This error message : `Input string was not in a correct format.`

Comment: wait.. it just a example for between numbers, i will modify my answer

Comment: what version of .Net framework you're using?, i already modified my answer

Comment: my code is tested in .Net 4. i will try in .net 3.5, just wait.

Comment: and i test in 3.5, and everything's fine. please check in what event you copy-paste the code?

Answer (score 0):

```
    Private Sub TextBox1_TextChanged(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As  System.EventArgs) Handles TextBox1.TextChanged

    Dim myRegex As New Regex("^[0-9]*\.?[0-9]{0,2}$")
    If myRegex.IsMatch(TextBox1.Text.Trim) = False Then
        MsgBox("Invalid characters found")
        Exit Sub
    Else
        If CDec(TextBox1.Text.Trim) < 0 OrElse CDec(TextBox1.Text.Trim) > 20 Then
            MsgBox("Enter value between 0.00 and 20.00")
            Exit Sub
        End If
    End If

    End Sub
```

Comment: Your regexp will accept for instance 100. That's why it is better to convert the string to the number before doing any comparison

Comment: @Necto:Yes the regexp will accept 100, but the second if condition will handle this. The regex is to avoid the minus sign (Eg: -10.00)